# Haskell Enumerations starting from 1

Tags: haskell

Consider the following method to create a start-at-1 enumeration in Haskell:

```
data Level = Lower | Middle | Upper
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

instance Enum Level where
    toEnum 1  = Lower
    toEnum 2  = Middle
    toEnum 3  = Upper

    fromEnum Lower  = 1
    fromEnum Middle = 2
    fromEnum Upper  = 3

instance Bounded Level where
    minBound = Lower
    maxBound = Upper
```

I'd rather not do the following:

```
data Level = DontUseThis | Lower | Middle | Upper
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

If not, is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Comment: _Why_ do you want this offset by one?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here that it makes a difference whether `fromEnum minBound` returns 0 or 1?

Comment: It's still not a start-at-1 enumeration, it's a start-at-Lower enumeration.

Comment: The code you wrote looks perfectly fine to me. It's correct, it's fast, and it takes damn near zero neurons to read.

Comment: I want to do this because Lower maps directly to 1 in the business logic.

Comment: @Ana: maybe an explicit conversion function `:: Level -> Int` makes more sense than using `Enum` then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to define the `Bounded` instance yourself. If you add `Bounded` to the list of derived typeclasses you should get identical behavior.

Secondly, the most straightforward way I can think of to accomplish this is to simply derive `Enum` and then define your own translation functions. So something like this:

```
data Level = Lower | Middle | Upper
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum)

toEnum' x = toEnum (x - 1)
fromEnum' x = (fromEnum x) + 1
```

Comment: Doesn't seem clean, but good idea. Is it possible to _hide_ the original toEnum and fromEnum and replace them with the new versions?

Comment: Sort of? You could add `import Prelude hiding (toEnum, fromEnum)` at the top and then put in your own definitions of those functions. This looks pretty similar to your original code, but the advantage is that the other 4 functions in the `Enum` typeclass are defined for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it a little bit more concise (well, if you have more than 3 constructors) using:

```
import Data.List (elemIndex)
import Data.Maybet (fromJust)

values = [Lower, Middle, Upper]  

instance Enum Level where
    toEnum n  = values !! (n-1)
    fromEnum k  = 1 + fromJust $ elemIndex k values
```

Comment: However that's quite expensive in terms of lookup time.

Comment: If this is really an issue, you can always use a `Map` and a `Vector` instead.